# Почему садятся на руки, если садятся на ноги?

Tags: фразеология

В транспорте часто можно услышать: "Посадите ребенка на руки". И вообще, когда кого-то сажают себе на колени, говорят, что "он сидит у меня на руках". Откуда такая путаница конечностей?)))

Answer (score 4):

Не слышала такого. У нас говорят: "Посадите на колени", а когда говорят "возьмите на руки", то берут на руки в стоячем положении. Если такая путаница происходит, то это не в языке, а в речи отдельных индивидуумов, когда они говорят не задумываясь, такое тоже бывает: скажешь, а потом увидишь, что глупость сказал, но не исправляешься. Поняли ведь-и ладно. Положение-то ребёнка похоже, бывает, что и сидя держишь именно на руках, а не на коленках.

Comment: >а когда говорят "возьмите на руки", то берут на руки в стоячем положении.    
  
Да нет, на руки вполне можно взять и сидя. Но именно *взять*, не посадить.
В остальном - согласен.

Answer (score 3):

У нас говорят "возьмите на руки", хотя ребенок, конечно, сидит потом на коленях у взрослого. Я думаю, здесь происходит метонимия. Берут ребенка руками, садят на колени - но так говорить долго,  вот и получается... Для разговорной речи вполне понятное явление.